# NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x75786f0'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray

```
CellData *cellData = [self.tableElements objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"name is %@",[self.tableElements objectAtIndex:1]);
        cell.lbl.text = cellData.name;
```

here am getting the error when i able to access my NSObject class variables.
self.tableElements is an array with elements parsed.

Comment: On which line your are getting this error?

Comment: at this line cell.lbl.text = cellData.name;

Comment: is self.tableElements of type array? and also what do u mean by CellData?

Comment: What is the console output for the NSLog you added ?

Comment: [980:11303] name is (
    "<CellData: 0x7139660>"
)
This is my console output.

Comment: Your log is a little useless, change it to `NSLog(@"name is %@",[self.tableElements objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);` and I bet you will find that NSArray is the type of object before you encounter your crash

Comment: @PKCoder self.tableElements is a NSMutablearray and CellData is a subclass of NSObject

Answer (score 1):

`cellData` is not what you think it is, you think it is a `CellData` object but it is actually an `NSArray`, double check what `self.tableElements` is holding.

Comment: self.tableElements are holding the objects of my CellData Class